# How to accept custom HTTP error codes with the Micronaut client?

Tags: http-status-codes, micronaut

I'm setting up an HTTP client to an external API. That server has unusual status codes in case of errors in the payload sent (310 to 323).

However, Micronaut's HTTP client throws an IllegalArgumentException when trying to parse that response, due to its limited known list of status codes (https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/master/http/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/HttpStatus.java)

Moreover, when trying to write an async client with the JavaRx library, that error does NOT lead to an error being thrown immediately. It instead hangs for a few seconds and throws an ReadTimeoutException.

I tried Kotlin extensions to extend the HttpStatus enum, but failed. Not sure it is really possible in the way it is used.

Here is the client code:

```
@Context
@Requires(beans = [FooConfiguration::class])
class FooClient(
    @Client("foo") private val httpClient: RxHttpClient,
    private val config: FooConfiguration
) {
    private val quoteOrderEndpoint = "/api/quote"

    private val AUTH_HEADER = "x-foo-bar"

    fun quoteOrder(quoteRequest: QuoteOrderRequest): Single<QuoteOrderResponse> {
        val body = JsonFormat.printer().print(quoteRequest)
        val httpRequest = HttpRequest.POST<Any>(quoteOrderEndpoint, body)
            .header(AUTH_HEADER, config.apiKey)

        return httpClient.exchange(httpRequest, String::class.java)
            .map { response ->
                val builder = QuoteOrderResponse.newBuilder()
                JsonFormat.parser().merge(response.body(), builder)
                builder.build()
            }.singleOrError()
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties("${ServiceHttpClientConfiguration.PREFIX}.foo")
class FooConfiguration {
    lateinit var apiKey: String
}
```

and here is the test code:

```
class FooClientTest {
    lateinit var client: FooClient
    lateinit var config: FooConfiguration

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        val rxHttpClient = RxHttpClient.create(URL("https://sandbox.foo.com"))
        config = FooConfiguration()
        config.apiKey = "***"
        client = FooClient(rxHttpClient, config)
    }

    @Test
    fun testQuoteOrder() {
        // This payload is incomplete and the API returns a 310 error.
        val request = QuoteOrderRequest.newBuilder()
            .build()
        val response = client.quoteOrder(request).blockingGet()
        assertEquals(request.customer.country, response.customer.country)
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
17:00:41.446 [multithreadEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN  i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid HTTP status code: 310
    at io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(HttpStatus.java:146)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.FullNettyClientHttpResponse.<init>(FullNettyClientHttpResponse.java:82)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1764)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1725)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:185)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsClientHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsClientHandler.java:180)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1429)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1199)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17:00:41.463 [multithreadEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN  io.sentry.dsn.Dsn - *** Couldn't find a suitable DSN, Sentry operations will do nothing! See documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/ ***
17:00:41.470 [multithreadEventLoopGroup-1-2] WARN  io.sentry.DefaultSentryClientFactory - No 'stacktrace.app.packages' was configured, this option is highly recommended as it affects stacktrace grouping and display on Sentry. See documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/#in-application-stack-frames

io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Read Timeout

    at io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.<clinit>(ReadTimeoutException.java:26)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient.lambda$null$28(DefaultHttpClient.java:1071)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableOnErrorNext$OnErrorNextSubscriber.onError(FlowableOnErrorNext.java:103)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTimeoutTimed$TimeoutSubscriber.onTimeout(FlowableTimeoutTimed.java:139)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTimeoutTimed$TimeoutTask.run(FlowableTimeoutTimed.java:170)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So, the questions are:

1) How can I add custom status codes to the HTTP client.

2) How to avoid the request timeout and throw directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `http-client` and there is, apparently, no workaround.

https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/2189

Comment: that fixed already